# Save video using opencv with H264 codec

Tags: python, docker, opencv, ffmpeg, h.264

This is beyond me and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have read that in order to have my video in h265 codec, I need to build opencv from source. Well, I did that, and I also did it for ffmpeg [Docker ffmpeg Compiler](https://github.com/srwareham/docker-ffmpeg-compiler). But I'm trying to run my application using docker, and I still can't get over the error:

```
[ERROR:0@93.327] global cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:3018 open Could not find encoder for codec_id=27, error: Encoder not found
[ERROR:0@93.327] global cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:3093 open VIDEOIO/FFMPEG: Failed to initialize VideoWriter
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.12-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the application code into the container
COPY . .

# Set ffmpeg and ffprobe binary files
RUN mv ffmpeg /usr/local/bin
RUN mv ffprobe /usr/local/bin

# Build opencv from source, to be able to use h264 codec.
RUN apt-get install -y cmake \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    python3-numpy \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
    libgstreamer1.0-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libopenexr-dev \
    libtiff-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    git

RUN git clone --depth 1 --branch 4.8.0 https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git && \
    git clone --depth 1 --branch 4.8.0 https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git && \
    cd opencv && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/app/opencv_contrib/modules ../ && \
    make -j"$(nproc)" && \
    make install

# Remove opencv github project
RUN rm -r opencv

# Remove opencv_contrib github project
RUN rm -r opencv_contrib

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files to disc
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

# Prevents Python from buffering stdout and stderr
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Install netcat to know when rabbitmq is running
RUN apt-get install -y netcat

# Set execute permissions
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x web_start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

I ran the command `./ffmpeg -i 57b3e3a7-ad22-469d-a7ff-cf76ba780664 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac output.mp4` to test ffmpeg and this was the result.

```
ffmpeg version N-112515-gba6a5e7a3d Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-libs=-static --extra-cflags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/root/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      58. 27.100 / 58. 27.100
  libavcodec     60. 30.102 / 60. 30.102
  libavformat    60. 15.101 / 60. 15.101
  libavdevice    60.  2.101 / 60.  2.101
  libavfilter     9. 11.100 /  9. 11.100
  libswscale      7.  4.100 /  7.  4.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '57b3e3a7-ad22-469d-a7ff-cf76ba780664':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2023-10-30T15:34:32.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 13 Pro Max
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 16.6
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2023-10-30T11:34:32-0400
  Duration: 00:00:03.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16264 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 16120 kb/s, 29.99 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-10-30T15:34:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : H.264
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 89 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-10-30T15:34:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2[0x3](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-10-30T15:34:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:3[0x4](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-10-30T15:34:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:4[0x5](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 34 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-10-30T15:34:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=30 lookahead_threads=5 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2023-10-30T11:34:32-0400
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 13 Pro Max
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 16.6
    encoder         : Lavf60.15.101
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1080x1920, q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-10-30T15:34:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.30.102 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-10-30T15:34:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.30.102 aac
[out#0/mp4 @ 0x5ae3440] video:2773kB audio:31kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.157082%
frame=  108 fps= 74 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2809kB time=00:00:03.59 bitrate=6393.3kbits/s speed=2.47x    
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] frame I:4     Avg QP:22.27  size: 48408
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] frame P:104   Avg QP:24.58  size: 25440
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] mb I  I16..4: 10.3% 82.9%  6.8%
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] mb P  I16..4:  4.6% 18.1%  0.8%  P16..4: 40.3%  6.9%  4.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:25.3%
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] 8x8 transform intra:78.0% inter:85.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 44.9% 29.1% 0.1% inter: 22.5% 23.3% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 17% 49% 14% 19%
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 25% 37%  3%  3%  5%  3%  2%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 30% 17%  3%  4%  8%  3%  2%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 67% 20% 12%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:1.9% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] ref P L0: 61.8% 10.4% 18.3%  9.4%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x5ae4c00] kb/s:6303.40
[aac @ 0x68c9880] Qavg: 119.986
```

The resulting video had an h264 codec. In my opinion, the problem is in opencv. Basically this is what I do in my python code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
shoot_frames = []
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if not ret:
       break
    if some_condition:
       shoot_frames.append(img)
    if len(shoot_frames) > 41:
       out1 = cv2.VideoWriter(upload_path(name , dir), cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1'), int(fps), (int(width), int(height)), True)
       for shoot_frame in shoot_frames:
           out1.write(shoot_frame)
       out1.release()
       shoot_frames = []
```

Output from `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())`:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.8.1 =====================================
  Version control:               4.8.1-dirty

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2023-09-27T14:20:56Z
    Host:                        Linux 5.15.0-1046-azure x86_64
    CMake:                       3.27.5
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /bin/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (7 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (35 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (5 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/bin/c++  (ver 10.2.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    ccache:                      YES
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          /lib64/libopenblas.so Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent /usr/local/lib/libpng.so /lib64/libz.so dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI:                           QT5
    QT:                          YES (ver 5.15.0 )
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.7)
    JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         /usr/local/lib/libpng.so (ver 1.6.40)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.5.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (59.37.100)
      avformat:                  YES (59.27.100)
      avutil:                    YES (57.28.100)
      swscale:                   YES (6.7.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2021.8 [2021.8.0]
           at:                   /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2021.8.0)
              at:                /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
    VA:                          NO
    Lapack:                      YES (/lib64/libopenblas.so)
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)
    Flatbuffers:                 builtin/3rdparty (23.5.9)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /io/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/python/cp37-cp37m/bin/python3.7 (ver 3.7.17)
    Libraries:                   libpython3.7m.a (ver 3.7.17)
    numpy:                       /home/ci/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.17.0)
    install path:                python/cv2/python-3

  Python (for build):            /opt/python/cp37-cp37m/bin/python3.7

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    Java:                        NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update**

I made my docker image more simpler, and therefore my question. Install ffmpeg from the repository:

```
FROM python:3.10.12-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install ffmpeg for opencv
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg

# Copy the application code into the container
COPY . .

# Build opencv from source, to be able to use h264 codec.
RUN apt-get install -y cmake \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    python3-numpy \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
    libgstreamer1.0-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libopenexr-dev \
    libtiff-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    git

RUN git clone --depth 1 --branch 4.8.0 https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git && \
    git clone --depth 1 --branch 4.8.0 https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git && \
    cd opencv && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/app/opencv_contrib/modules -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON ../ && \
    make -j"$(nproc)" && \
    make install

# Remove opencv github project
RUN rm -r opencv

# Remove opencv_contrib github project
RUN rm -r opencv_contrib

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files to disc
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

# Prevents Python from buffering stdout and stderr
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Install netcat to know when rabbitmq is running
RUN apt-get install -y netcat

# Set execute permissions
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x web_start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Run the following commands inside the docker container:

```
$ ffmpeg -version

ffmpeg version 4.1.11-0+deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

```
$ ffmpeg -i cf91f302-c357-49ba-b59c-bcfb8b7f4866 -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 output.mp4

ffmpeg version 4.1.11-0+deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cf91f302-c357-49ba-b59c-bcfb8b7f4866':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2023-10-31T10:38:42.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 13 Pro Max
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 16.6
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2023-10-31T06:38:42-0400
  Duration: 00:00:04.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15915 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 15767 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2023-10-31T10:38:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : H.264
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 89 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-10-31T10:38:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-10-31T10:38:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
    Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-10-31T10:38:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
    Stream #0:4(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 34 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-10-31T10:38:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2023-10-31T06:38:42-0400
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 13 Pro Max
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 16.6
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x1920, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
      creation_time   : 2023-10-31T10:38:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-10-31T10:38:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
frame=  127 fps= 27 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2005kB time=00:00:04.24 bitrate=3866.2kbits/s speed=0.909x    
video:1964kB audio:36kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.282549%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] frame I:1     Avg QP:21.43  size: 36791
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] frame P:59    Avg QP:23.61  size: 22380
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] frame B:67    Avg QP:24.20  size:  9743
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] consecutive B-frames: 20.5% 22.0% 16.5% 40.9%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] mb I  I16..4: 29.4% 58.6% 11.9%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] mb P  I16..4: 15.0% 21.8%  1.3%  P16..4: 26.1%  7.5%  3.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:25.2%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] mb B  I16..4:  1.9%  1.7%  0.1%  B16..8: 36.3%  3.6%  0.5%  direct: 3.9%  skip:52.1%  L0:42.9% L1:52.1% BI: 5.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] 8x8 transform intra:56.2% inter:86.6%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 19.5% 27.3% 2.1% inter: 11.7% 18.9% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] i16 v,h,dc,p: 25% 54%  8% 12%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 25% 44%  1%  2%  2%  2%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 45% 13%  2%  7%  6%  6%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] i8c dc,h,v,p: 62% 27% 10%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] Weighted P-Frames: Y:3.4% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] ref P L0: 65.2% 18.0% 12.2%  4.6%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] ref B L0: 89.1%  9.3%  1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] ref B L1: 97.2%  2.8%
[libx264 @ 0x55db965ee980] kb/s:3798.37
[aac @ 0x55db965edf00] Qavg: 125.454
```

The errors persist.

```
>>> import cv2
>>> out = cv2.VideoWriter("./out.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1'), 30, (800, 600), True)
[ERROR:0@91.872] global cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:3018 open Could not find encoder for codec_id=27, error: Encoder not found
[ERROR:0@91.872] global cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:3093 open VIDEOIO/FFMPEG: Failed to initialize VideoWriter
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does your Python code look like?

Comment: I edited my question to add the python code

Comment: what ffmpeg did you build your opencv against? how did you install this opencv so it's known to python? did you install any prebuilt opencv-python packages? -- `avc1` is correct. if *that* ffmpeg were capable, it would have worked... unless the video *container* is wrong. what suffix does the output file name have in `upload_path(name, dir)`?

Comment: 1- well, I don't know if it is the correct way, but I am using a generated ffmpeg, using the github project that I specify in my question.
2- the way I generate opencv is by following the official steps described here https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html.
3- the suffix/extension is mp4

Comment: @ldiaz997. You are running Python 3.7. Why not update Python 3.12.0rc3?

Comment: @toyota i am running python 3.10.12 from docker image

Comment: Yon have 2 ...3.7 and 3.12 on your raspberry pi. Right!

Comment: I am looking at this Python (for build):            /opt/python/cp37-cp37m/bin/python3.7

Comment: Well, my application and my docker image not run on Raspberry pi, and in no step I select version 3.7. The version of python I would expect to use is the one specified in the dockerfile. Apparently, when I build opencv, python 3.7 is being installed?

Comment: Read this, it Looks like a license issue https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/207